# Cmake and regex dont work as expected

Tags: cmake

I have two variables in an text file that I would like to exhange. [V1] and [V2]. When I run my program it only changes one of them. Why?

```
    #Read up into variable
    file (STRINGS "myfile.txt" v1)
    #Store text to replace in variable (we need to escape the '[' and ']' since we will use a regexp later on)
    set(v1_placeholder "\\[v1\\]")
    set(v2_placeholder "\\[v2\\]")
    #New reading of documents to process
    set(doc_files [v1]_Hello_Documentation.txt myfile.txt)
    #Lets iterate over each documentation file
    foreach(doc_file ${doc_files})
      message(STATUS "Proccessing document file: " ${doc_file})
      #Read up content of documentation file
      file(READ ${doc_file} FILE_CONTENT)

      #Remove occurences of [v2] with nothing
      string(REGEX REPLACE "${v2_placeholder}" "" MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT "${FILE_CONTENT}")

      #Replace occurences of [v1] with the real variable in the content
      string(REGEX REPLACE "${v1_placeholder}" "${V1}" MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT "${FILE_CONTENT}")
      #Replace occurences of [v1] with the real variable in the file name
      string(REGEX REPLACE "${v1_placeholder}" "${V1}" MODIFIED_FILE_NAME "${doc_file}")

      #Write modified content back into modifed file name
      file(WRITE ${MODIFIED_FILE_NAME} "${MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT}")
      #Add the files to the package in dir /doc
      install (FILES ${MODIFIED_FILE_NAME} DESTINATION doc)
    endforeach(doc_file)
```

---

after I have run this my file will look liket this: (it never deletes the v2.)

The application is currently r.

Main features
When running Hello r the user is presented with the text "Hello World" on stdout.

```
History
[v2]
r
a
b
c 
d
```

Comment: how does the file look at the start? Please use code tags so we can also see in how many lines it is.

Comment: The application is currently [v1].

        Main features When running Hello [v1] the user is presented with the text "Hello World" on stdout.
        History
        [v2]
        a
        b
        c 
        d

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make enough sense of your writting.

Comment: That is how the file looks at the beginning. All the vX is exchanged or should be.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass `MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT` instead of `FILE_CONTENT` to the second call to `string(REGEX REPLACE`, i.e.:

```
  #Remove occurences of [v2] with nothing
  string(REGEX REPLACE "${v2_placeholder}" "" MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT "${FILE_CONTENT}")

  #Replace occurences of [v1] with the real variable in the content
  string(REGEX REPLACE "${v1_placeholder}" "${V1}" MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT "${MODIFIED_FILE_CONTENT}")
```